# Accessing Script Template Data From Model With Magnolia Java

Tags: java, templates, magnolia

I need to access the data being input through the Magnolia script template, from the Magnolia Java model.

I have tried setting up parameters and definitions. I have tried using different properties of the definition and content Node.

```
public FormModel(Node content, ConfiguredTemplateDefinition definition, RenderingModel<?> parent) {
    super(content, definition, parent);
}

public String execute() {

    HttpServletRequest request = MgnlContext.getWebContext().getRequest();
    if ("POST".equals(request.getMethod())) {
        try {
            //Access the name input from the template script
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.print(e);
        }
    }

    return super.execute();
}
```

}

```
<form method="post">
    <div>
        <label>Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

I want to be able to access the value of input in the Java code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the `modelClass` attribute in your template definition, and `FormModel` should extend `info.magnolia.rendering.model.RenderingModelImpl<>`. You didn't specify if you did any of these, so it's very hard to guess what might be wrong there.

If you're using YAML, the definition should look like this:

```
renderType: freemarker
templateScript: /my-module/templates/components/home.ftl
modelClass: my.awesome.FormModel
```